# How to add up and down arrow in select field? Please see attached img

Tags: html, css

I want up and down arrow in select field

[image]

How would I code that in HTML/CSS?

Comment: You want in select (Combo Box) or in Textt Box

Comment: I want it in select where I can select up or down arrow to select different year.. and why is my question given negative review I could not upload image due to my low point so I added link ..And I am newbie for this forum so really hard to understand the flow

Comment: @sunjeep people downvoted becuase you didn't show your effort here. what you have tried to achieve this.

Comment: @sunjeep glad to help. Hope from next time take care of it. And  I think your issue is solved?

Comment: Have a look at the [help] to see how to ask questions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's simple use.

```html
<input type="number" value="2017"/>
```

There is no need of css.

You can set min and max value like:

```
<input type="number" min="1980" max="2020" value="2017">
```

Refer [this link.](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_min.asp)

Comment: thanks for your answer but Would I be able to add multiple years? so that I can change with up and down arrows?

Comment: @sunjeep multiple year means?

Comment: @ketan ok thanks bro I got the code dont know how to share here

Comment: @sunjeep You can accept/mark it as a answer if it solved you issue. Or Share you answer if it different.

Comment: @sunjeep i edit my answer i think this is what you want.

Comment: @ketan yes I got the answer thanks bro and will mark it as solved

Comment: @ketan bro how do I mark as answer or solved? I dont see any things like that

Comment: @sunjeep Welcome bro. ok np glad to help. you can click on right symbol below my 5 vote to mark it as a answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
<input type="number" value="2007">
```

for your reference:[Use Link](http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-number.php)